If I have a simple pendulum performing oscillations, whose string is snapped when it is at an extreme position, what will happen?
If I have a simple pendulum performing oscillations, whose string is snapped when it is at an extreme position, will it immediately fall vertically downwards because of gravity or will it continue upwards in a parabolic motion and then return downwards? I believe it will fall down because Kinetic Energy required to facilitate further upward movement against the force of gravity is 0, and hence, it shall fall down to neutralise the difference in its potential energy. Is this reasoning correct?

At the extreme position (max height), the mass on the end is momentarily at rest.  If the string breaks at that moment, you just have a mass in the air acted on only by gravity.  It will drop straight down just as it would if you held it in that position in your hand and let it go.

And if say, the string was snapped when the pendulum is at the mean position (i.e. it has maximum velocity) will it fall straight down to earth or will it continue a parabolic trajectory as it falls down because of the previous kinetic energy

It will follow a parabola in the second case, same as it was shot from a cannon with the same horizontal velocity.
